# Cannot match exact number within an array in R

Tags: arrays, numbers, matching, grepl, exact-match

This must be a trivial one but after many, many trials and errors I need to ask this.

I would like to find a whole number within a numerical array, e.g. `14` in `c(1,14,144)`.

The code I tried reads

```
dayNo <- 14
which(grepl(dayNo, c(1,14,144))==TRUE)
```

I get `2` & `3`. The results I am looking for is `2`.

Another one is

```
dayNo <- 14
which(grepl("\\bdayNo\\b", c(1,14,144))==TRUE)
```

but I get as result `integer(0)`.

Any ideas would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In this case this simple solution works just fine
`which(dayNo==c(1,14,144))`and gives as expected `2`